# getting single data out of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

from this var dump:

```
Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [535051281] => Array
                (
                    [clan_id] => 500040775
                    [nickname] => tiktak1999
                    [logout_at] => 1686514280
                )

        )

)
```

i would like to get only the clan_id and nickname to push into a database
but for the life of me, i tryed every iteration i could think of and find.
but to no avail.

2e problem would be that data -> [535051281] will change upon the user and will vary every time.

this is my code as of now.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recruitement2";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


//$jsonobj = include "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&account_id=".$row["gameid"]."&fields=clan_id%2Cnickname%2Clogout_at";
$jsonobj = file_get_contents ("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&account_id=".$row["gameid"]."&fields=clan_id%2Cnickname%2Clogout_at");

$json = (json_decode($jsonobj, true));
echo '<pre>'.print_r($json, true).'</pre>';
echo "<br><br>hier komt de enkele info<br><br>";

foreach($json as $row) {
       foreach($row['data'] as $k) {
           foreach($k['535051281'] as $l) {
             echo $l['535051281']['clan_id'];
             echo $l['535051281']['nickname'];
             ;
       }
    }
}

 } 
 }
```

throwing this error,

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /data/sites/web/mentals-royal-army-of-legendsnl/www/test.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /data/sites/web/mentals-royal-army-of-legendsnl/www/index.php(82): include() #1 {main} thrown in /data/sites/web/mentals-royal-army-of-legendsnl/www/test.php on line 18

any help would be greatly appreciated!

ive been hammering on this for 3 hours scraping the web for every solution i could find.
i cant get it working.

Comment: Why are you iterating over _all_ entries on the top level - when you are only interested in what is below the `data` key? _Because_ you are looping over everything, the first item you encounter in your loop, is the _text_ `ok`. Now you are trying to loop over _that_ value - and therefor you of course get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the first element in `data`, then you can get the `clan_id` and `nickname` in a few simple steps:

```
    $userData = reset($json['data']);
    $clanId = $userData['clan_id'];
    $nickname = $userData['nickname'];
    // ... your code here
```

Comment: you absolute hero! it works like a charm! im just a simple guy trying to get something to work and you just fixed hours of frustrations for me. thank you very much :) i also feel kinda stupid i could not find this solution myself, it looks so "simple"  sigh.